# filter array object from redux react typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, filter, react-redux, include

I'm mapping an array object that is obtained by redux state. I need to create a search filter that filters the array based on the key `name`. I'm struggling with the this filter, it just doesn't work and I'm going kind of crazy trying various ways.
`items` contains the array object, `filtered` contains the typed text from the input, all of those I can get from the redux state and they are saved to props using `mapStateToProps`

State:

```
items: [{name: "bla"}, {..}, {..}] (50 objects in array)
filtered: "test"
```

reducer:

```
case SEARCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtered: action.value
      };
```

component:

```
    const Tournaments = (props: TournamentInterface) => {
      const {
        items,
        filtered
      } = props;
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state: { tournaments: TournamentInterface }) => {
      return {
        items: state.tournaments.items,
        loading: state.tournaments.loading,
        error: state.tournaments.error,
        filtered: state.tournaments.filtered
      };
    };
    
        return (
         <ItemContainer>
        {items &&
                !loading &&
                items
                  .filter((item: any) => item.name.toLowerCase() === filtered)
                  .map(
                    (
                      item: {
                        name: string;
                        game: React.ReactNode;
                        participants: {
                          current: React.ReactNode;
                          max: React.ReactNode;
                        };
                        startDate: Date;
                      },
                      index: number
                    ) => (
                      <div className="item" key={index}>
                        <H6>{item.name}</H6>
                       </div>
                    )
                  )}
         </ItemContainer>
          );
};
```

Comment: oh hey I just added includes() this and it works:  .filter((item: any) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filtered))
          .map(). But if you can see a nicer way to create this please post an answer.

Comment: You can do the filter in a selector function and use that in mapStateToProps. This moves logic out of the component and into a selector you can re use for other component if needed.

Comment: Hey, I'm writing up an answer for you, but if you could post your `TournamentInterface` I can make sure that I get it right.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to unpack here.  You should not need to assign a type *inside* a `.map` callback because the type will be known if the array itself is typed correctly.  But clearly it's not.  So we need to fix your types!

You haven't included your `TournamentInterface` type but I can get an idea of what it is by working backwards. Since these items are coming from Redux the properties need a more specific type than `ReactNode` since some of the types that are assignable to `ReactNode` are not serializable.  Your dates should be stored as raw timestamps rather than `Date` objects for the same reason.

Try this:

```
interface Item {
  name: string;
  game: string;
  participants: {
    current: number;
    max: number;
  };
  startDate: number;
}

interface TournamentInterface {
  items: Item[];
  loading: boolean;
  error?: string | null;
  filtered: string;
}

type RootState = {
  tournaments: TournamentInterface;
};
```

---

> I read somewhere its better not to filter the state directly in redux, but in the component. Yes, when I try that the items array is changed in the state and doesn't not return to show all the objects because it has been filtered.

I agree with that first sentence completely and the second sentence is why.  If you filter the `items` property then you lose items.  If you store the filtered array in a separate property then you have duplicated data.

> You can do the filter in a selector function and use that in mapStateToProps. This moves logic out of the component and into a selector you can re use for other component if needed. – HMR

I like @HMR's suggestion here.  You can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create a memoized selector that only returns a new value if the state changes.  I'm using your filter function from the comments.

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const selectFilteredItems = createSelector(
  // input selectors
  (state: RootState) => state.tournaments.items,
  (state: RootState) => state.tournaments.filtered,
  // combiner - types here are inferred correctly
  (items, filtered) =>
    items.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filtered.toLowerCase())
    )
);
```

---

I'm going to use `useSelector` instead of `mapStateToProps` as that's the newer, current approach.  We can make use of the `createSelectorHook` utility so that the `RootState` type is automatically inferred.

```
import { createSelectorHook } from "react-redux";

const useSelector = createSelectorHook<RootState>();
```

```
const Tournaments = () => {
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.tournaments.loading);
  const filteredItems = useSelector(selectFilteredItems);

  return (
    <ItemContainer>
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        filteredItems.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="item" key={index}>
            <h6>{item.name}</h6>
            <div>Started: {new Date(item.startDate).toDateString()}</div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </ItemContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to filter in redux.

```
case SEARCH:
 return {
   items: state.items.filter((item: any) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filtered.toLowerCase())),
   filtered: action.value
 };
```

Comment: I read somewhere its better not to filter the state directly in redux, but in the component. Yes, when I try that the items array is changed in the state and doesn't not return to show all the objects because it has been filtered. But good idea.

Comment: Actually you don't need to keep items in redux if they are not useable in other components, also filter key too. ( read article about "You don't need redux" ) . Instead store in component state and pass down where you need.

Comment: I would love to not use redux but its a requirement of the project.